# SQLite full text search catalog

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, indexing, catalog

I wonder if the following is possible with fts(3/4) for SQLite.
I created a table with some data using fts3.

If i for example search for e* i get everything that starts with ^e
But can i also search the index/catalog for the specific words that starts with e?

So that i only get the results of that words back like; elliot, elo,eehh.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3

```
       SELECT * FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'lin*';
```

Will return the docs that contain a word starting with "lin".  You only want the words that match, not the context?  Maybe the "snippets" feature will help you. And you may find this thread of interest:

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg49345.html

Comment: This will return a set of rows which contain lin*, but what i want to achieve, is to return words that are indexed by sqlite. So for example it should return in your example linux, linear,linwhatever...but not the rows that containt lin*

Comment: We are typing at same time. See appended info.

Comment: snippets are what i was looking for.Sqlite indicates which words compare to the input. The only things left is to extract the words, so that we only see the exact word(s)

Comment: Good, Donal's answer also provides needed detail.

Comment: @Grezly: `...what i want to achieve, is to return words that are indexed by sqlite`. If you want to see the list of words that are in the full-text index, see http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#fts4aux "Direct Access to the Full-Text Index".

Answer (score 2):

The FTS engine provides that information via the [`offsets`](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_1) virtual function.

```
SELECT offsets(docs) FROM docs WHERE docs MATCH 'e*';
```

As the documentation says:

> For a SELECT query that uses the full-text index, the offsets() function returns a text value containing a series of space-separated integers. For each term in each phrase match of the current row, there are four integers in the returned list. Each set of four integers is interpreted as follows:
>
> 1. The column number that the term instance occurs in (0 for the leftmost column of the FTS table, 1 for the next leftmost, etc.).
> 2. The term number of the matching term within the full-text query expression. Terms within a query expression are numbered starting from 0 in the order that they occur.
> 3. The byte offset of the matching term within the column.
> 4. The size of the matching term in bytes.

How to extract that information is up to you and how you integrate your code with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation of the snippet function](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_4_2) is rather vague regarding its 6th parameter because the algorithm uses a best-score approach to find the snippet.

Nevertheless in my application i get a clean extract of the original terms I am looking for with the request :

```
select snippet(docs,'','','', -1, 1) from docs where docs match 'e*';
```

It may help in your case ; this in-database solution helped me because i didn't want to extract the terms in code located outside of the db. It works if you are searching for single words (no space, OR, .. in the MATCH query)