# Full-Text Search for SQLite Engine. Where can I fifnd it?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I would like to know, where can I find a detailed information about a realization of full-text search in sqlite db? Is it a program code an only source for this?
It works great (FTS3 and FTS4 extentions), but I need to know a theoretical basis for the realization.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just send you a perfect and detailed link about it:  http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3

Similar question exists:
       [SQLite full text search catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519854/sqlite-full-text-search-catalog)